# Trying to return a value from API with JSON

Tags: json, swift, api

Im trying to get data from newsapi.org/.

parseJSON returns error, and for some reason it can't get the data from NewsData.

I think there is some problem with my NewsData properties, which parseJSON func can't figure out the data.

here is the JSON (from urlString):

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 38,
"articles": [

  {
    "source": {
      "id": "fox-news",
      "name": "Fox News"
    },
    "author": "Ryan Gaydos",
    "title": "Errol Spence Jr. retains welterweight titles in victory over Danny Garcia - Fox News",
    "description": "Errol Spence Jr. defeated Danny Garcia via unanimous decision Saturday night to retain the WBC and IBF welterweight titles.",
    "url": "https://www.foxnews.com/sports/errol-spence-jr-danny-garcia-boxing-2020",
    "urlToImage": "https://static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2020/12/Errol-Spence2.jpg",
    "publishedAt": "2020-12-06T05:39:59Z",
    "content": "Errol Spence Jr. defeated Danny Garcia via unanimous decision Saturday night to retain the WBC and IBF welterweight titles.\r\nThe judges scored the fight&nbsp;116-112, 116-112, 117-111 in 

favor of Spence.\r… [+1417 chars]"
      }
    ]
}
```

and here is my code:

NewsData.Swift:

```
struct NewsData: Codable {
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let content: String
}
```

NewsManager.Swift:

```
func getNews() {
    let urlString = "\(baseURL)&apiKey=\(apiKey)"
    
    if let url = URL(string: urlString){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)        
            } else {
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let news = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        print(news)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }   
}

func parseJSON(_ data: Data) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let encodedData = try encoder.decode(NewsData.self, from: data)

        let des = encodedData.articles[0].content
        let title = encodedData.articles[0].title
        let content = encodedData.articles[0].content
        
        return content
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

the return error is:

```
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: Looking at the JSON there is a missing `]` for closing the `articles` array. And the error will probably say somethink like that too.

Comment: Sorry my bad I missed the ] . still getting error.

Comment: If you get an error then include it as part of the question.

Comment: Your struct model misses a lot of elements.

Comment: @ElTomato how is that an issue?

Comment: Looks to me like the second article does not have a `content` value, make that property optional in your struct.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoakimDanielson I changed the Article properties to optional and it worked. Would you please explain why this happened ? Because when I open the url with browser ,JSON shows that all properties here have the String value.

Comment: Sorry, I can not possibly know why the API sends data the way it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DecodingError` is one of the most precise and understandable errors ever.

Please read it entirely.

> valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

There are three significant information:

1. **What**: `valueNotFound` indicates that somewhere a value is missing
2. **Where**: The `CodingPath` is similar to a key path, concatenating the `stringValue`s results in:

   ```
   articles[1].content
   ```

   which points to the property **content** in the **second** item of **articles**
3. **Why**: The `debugDescription` describes the actual error:

   - `Expected` indicates the *wrong* type → a non-optional `String`
   - `found` indicates the *right* type → `<null>` is not a value and requires an optional type

**Solution: Declare `content` as optional**

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let content: String?
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vadian for thorough explanation, What I don't understand is that the content property in the JSON has a value of String! and not Optional. but source.id in the second item of Article in JSON, is null. How does that affect the Content property that forces me to use Optional String?

Comment: Without knowing the JSON I have no idea.